# BlueZ API - OOB process?

Tags: bluez, pairing

How works OOB as pairing process for a LE setup, so NO classic bluetooth bredr?

Regardless of NFC as wireless transfer mechanism I was thinking of doing the following process manually as proof of concept.

Read out the local oob (btmgmt local-oob) and pass the oob to the other device that needs to be paired with the remote-oob cmd in btmgmt.

But when trying to readout the local-oob I get an error message the operation is not supported. The bluetooth adapters I'm using are single mode, BLE.

Any idea what could be wrong? Or what the proper way is to implement OOB for a BLE setup.

So far I didn't find any well documented process how to use the BlueZ API or tooling for doing this OOB process.

Thanks in advance, 
Best regards,
Frank